# How can I adjust the color bar position if there are multiple subplots in a figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to move my color bar near a specific subplot in my figure, I searched the past questions, nearly all the answer needs the imshow() function, is there any different solution?
[this is my current figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVz5K.png)

I'll put a few of my codes down there if anyone wondered.

```
fig,(axe1,axe2)=plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(40,40))
axe1.barh(count['platform'],count['numbers'],0.8,color=color)
axe2.barh(combine['platform'],combine['score'],color='pink')
fig.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='hsv',norm=col.Normalize(0,1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

See: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/colorbar_placement.html

Maybe to put next to both axes:

```py
fig,(axe1,axe2)=plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(40,40), constrained_layout=True)
...
fig.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='hsv',norm=col.Normalize(0,1)), ax=[axe1, axe2])
```

or just next to axe1:

```py
fig.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='hsv',norm=col.Normalize(0,1)), ax=axe1)
```